# ?Loaded .RData file is unable to display Chinese characters in R?

Tags: r, macos

```
load("/Users/nicholas/Desktop/RDATA/example/ch2/example2_1.RData")
head(example2_1,10)
```

result turns out to be messy code as follows,

\xd0Ա\xf0 ţ\xc4\xccƷ\xc5\xc6

1   \xc4\xd0   \xd2\xc1\xc0\xfb

2          Ů     \xc8\xfd\u052a

3          Ů   \xb9\xe2\xc3\xf7

4   \xc4\xd0   \xd2\xc1\xc0\xfb

5   \xc4\xd0          \xc3\xc9ţ

6   \xc4\xd0   \xd2\xc1\xc0\xfb

7          Ů   \xb9\xe2\xc3\xf7

8   \xc4\xd0     \xc8\xfd\u052a

9          Ů   \xd2\xc1\xc0\xfb

10  \xc4\xd0          \xc3\xc9ţ

My R sets up on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2,

is it because of encoding setup or whatever? How can I display Chinese characters correctly?